# White light interferometer, how much precise must be?

Tags: interference, home-experiment, microscopy, optics

I am trying to build a small interferometer, but after many attempt, I still can't see any fringes or interference effect.

How much precise need to be the surfaces and the angles to see interference with white light? With collimated lasers, it is easy to get interference even with a very rough setup.  I need to understand if I'm making some mistakes, or just need much more precision, or there is some trickery (eg. polarizers, phase plates..) to make it work.

Description of the setup:

- A Led lamp with white light and diffuser as light source
- The beamsplitter is made by two Porro prisms (45 deg) glued with an half-silvered mirror in the middle.
- The half-silvered mirror has been obtained by etching/scraping a piece of beauty mirror.
- The reference mirror is a piece of beauty mirror, glued to one face of the prism.
- The test mirror is free to move.

All surface are (I believe) reasonably flat; but angles and parallelisms are pretty inaccurate (say, 1 degree error).

The setup is on a microscope stage, and I (try) to observe the interference patterns with a 4x microscope objective. (0.10 NA)
I can manage to get in sharp focus both test and reference mirror at the same time (same lengths for the two light paths that should interfere), but no interference fringes. I was hoping to see at least something.

Below a drawing of my setup. I tried two other beamsplitter, one obtained by gluing two prisms (the glue between the prisms is more or less semi-reflective) and the other with a thin (170 micron) glass panel that does some Fresnel reflection.

Summary:
Is white light, large aperture interferometry possible with a crude setup?  Or all must be parallel and collimate within half micron?  Or something is missing, like collimated illumination?

[image: Setup microscope interferometer]

Comment: Any working white-light interferometer will also show interference for coherent light. Red diode lasers are quite inexpensive (people buy them as cat toys). The interference pattern (or lack thereof) from a coherent source might help you decide why you aren’t seeing any white-light interference; your question in its current form suggests a number of possible issues.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to steal a laser pointer to a nearby cat and see what happens. Bit scared of looking at a laser through a microscope, will need to mount a camera sensor.

Comment: Why would you use white light?

Comment: No lasers at home for now.  Also, with a laser, I would need to spread and refocus the beam, so to get large aperture illumination; fear that will be complicated. My purpose is to observe small features, so need large aperture.  White light diffuse was easy.

Comment: I can't speak to home-made setups, but I did spend some time with a dedicated purpose-built commercial Michelson interferometer in undergraduate optics labs using both monochromatic and white light. As a general rule, white light is *extremely* finicky, and interference only happens over a very narrow window. The only way we could get it to work was to use laser light to align the interferometer to truly zero path difference (adjusting to get broader fringes, until they turn into a circular Newton's-ring-like pattern) and then using white light. Starting with white light never worked.

Comment: the max mismatch depends on the light source you use, and indeed it can be very small with white light. The more uncorrelated is the light (the broader the spectrum), the shortest is the correlation length. I don't know for a white LED, but it could go down to tens of microns? in that case you need to place the mirror on a stage moved by a micrometer screw. More [details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_light_interferometry)

Comment: Yes that mirror position may be another issue; with the microscope setup I was able to put the two mirrors within 50 micron - which likely isn't precise enough